# cordova camera plugin - possible to get portrait mode to work on iOS?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I'm curious if it's possible to get portrait mode (not orientation, but the bokeh effect) working in the cordova-camera-plugin? I know that this mode isn't available on all iOS devices.

Comment: no, it's not possible

Comment: thanks. any idea why not?

Comment: The component it uses doesn’t have that mode, don’t know why, ask Apple